# MenuItem's icon color not changing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I am trying to change the text and icon color of my MenuItem through code. I've searched the solutions how to do it and the text is being changed but the icon is not.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
    public void setItemOptionColor(boolean isActive){
            MenuItem menuItem = mDrawerNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.my_item);
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
            Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();

            if(isActive){
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.accent)), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
                DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable,getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));  
                //drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                //drawable.setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
            }
            menuItem.setIcon(drawable);
            menuItem.setTitle(spannableString);
        }
```

So right now to change the icon color I am using `DrawableCompat` but there are also my two other attempts being commented out. All those 3 methods are not working.

Also I will add that even though I removed setting default tint to white from xml file the icon is still being displayed white even though drawable file is originally black. And I don't know why it is like that, maybe it is somehow connected to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setItemOptionColor(boolean isActive) {
        mDrawerNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); // add this line
        MenuItem menuItem = mDrawerNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.my_item);
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
        Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();

        if (isActive) {
            int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.accent);
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
            DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
        }
        menuItem.setIcon(drawable);
        menuItem.setTitle(spannableString);
    }
```

Comment: So what did you actually changed?

Comment: mDrawerNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

Comment: anyway you code logic of this method is weird, also colors of drawer items (checked/unchecked) could be easy defined directly in xml

Comment: But I need to change them dynamically in some cases